# Writing a Basic "C" Program in Mac Terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal

I was curious if I could write C programs in the Mac Terminal. It seems yes, but when I start trying to use Strings, I get errors when compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
        string s = "chris";
        printf("hello %s \n", s);
}
```

When I compile this I get a message saying `use of undeclared identifier 'string' - string s = "chris";`

I have trying adding `using namespace std;` but is says that `using` is undefined. I have tried both `#include <string>` and `#include <string.h>`

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no "`string`" in C; it sounds like you're mixing C and C++ concepts.

Comment: And in C++ you have `#include <string>` to use `std::string`. But most importantly, don't try to write C or C++ trying random stuff, get yourself a book first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is a standard C++ library class.  Use `const char *` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
        const char *s = "chris";
        printf("hello %s \n", s);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. I am following along with an online course and they are saying they are using "C" and they are using strings, maybe my lines got crossed somewhere.

Comment: @Chris Well unless you do `typedef const char *string;` before `main()`, then I think you have your wires crossed.  If they are using C++ then that `%s` in the `printf()` will break and you generally use `std::cout` instead with C++.

Comment: Even if you did typedef it, `string` is a reserved identifier in C, so it would still be wrong.